llvm/IR/Attributes.inc: No such file or directory when write toy compiler using LLVM
I want to use flex bison and llvm to generate IR,in my project, I use Clion as ide, and I correctly include all the header files that llvm needs.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)

project(Compiler)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17) include_directories("D:\\DEVELOPMENT\\LLVM\\llvm-project\\llvm\\include")

add_executable(Compiler
        lexer.yy.cpp
        parser.tab.hpp
        Ast.hpp
        Symbol.hpp
        Symbol.cpp
        parser.tab.cpp
        Ast.cpp )

But in Intrinsics.h and Attributes.h(2 header files that llvm provides), errors occurs in these two lines:
#include "llvm/IR/IntrinsicEnums.inc"
#include "llvm/IR/Attributes.inc"

when compiling with cmake, the errors are:
====================[ Build | Compiler | Debug 

]================================
D:\DEVELOPMENT\CLion\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe --build C:\Users\20786\Desktop\C++\CompilerPrinciple\ExperimentEdition\cmake-build-debug --target Compiler -j 14
[1/4] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Compiler.dir/Ast.cpp.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/Compiler.dir/Ast.cpp.obj 
D:\DEVELOPMENT\mingw64\bin\c++.exe  -ID:/DEVELOPMENT/LLVM/llvm-project/llvm/include -g -fdiagnostics-color=always -MD -MT CMakeFiles/Compiler.dir/Ast.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\Compiler.dir\Ast.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/Compiler.dir/Ast.cpp.obj -c C:/Users/20786/Desktop/C++/CompilerPrinciple/ExperimentEdition/Ast.cpp
In file included from D:/DEVELOPMENT/LLVM/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/IR/Module.h:22,
                 from C:/Users/20786/Desktop/C++/CompilerPrinciple/ExperimentEdition/Ast.cpp:7:
D:/DEVELOPMENT/LLVM/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/IR/Attributes.h:89:14: fatal error: llvm/IR/Attributes.inc: No such file or directory
   89 |     #include "llvm/IR/Attributes.inc"
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

I have searched for solutions, but I only find one.It says that I should follow the document to compile the llvm-project source code so that .inc file will be generated. But when I finished that, neither did I see the .inc file nor the llvm-tblgen tool in /build/bin.My steps are as below:
cmake -S llvm -B build -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release"

then the building infos are:
> CMake Deprecation Warning at
> D:/DEVELOPMENT/LLVM/llvm-project/cmake/Modules/CMakePolicy.cmake:6
> (cmake_policy):   The OLD behavior for policy CMP0114 will be removed
> from a future version   of CMake.
> 
>   The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all 
> policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only
> under   specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported
> to the NEW   behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD. Call
> Stack (most recent call first):   CMakeLists.txt:6 (include)
> 
> 
> CMake Deprecation Warning at
> D:/DEVELOPMENT/LLVM/llvm-project/cmake/Modules/CMakePolicy.cmake:11
> (cmake_policy):   The OLD behavior for policy CMP0116 will be removed
> from a future version   of CMake.
> 
>   The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all 
> policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only
> under   specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported
> to the NEW   behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD. Call
> Stack (most recent call first):   CMakeLists.txt:6 (include)
> 
> 
> -- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
> -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
> -- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
> -- Found assembler: D:/DEVELOPMENT/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
> -- Check for working C compiler: D:/DEVELOPMENT/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
> -- Detecting C compile features
> -- Detecting C compile features - done
> -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
> -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
> -- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/DEVELOPMENT/mingw64/bin/c++.exe - skipped
> -- Detecting CXX compile features
> -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
> -- Found Python3: C:/DEVELOPMENT/Python3/python.exe (found suitable version "3.11.2", minimum required is "3.8") found components:
> Interpreter
> -- Looking for dlfcn.h
> -- Looking for dlfcn.h - not found
> -- Looking for errno.h
> -- Looking for errno.h - found
> -- Looking for fcntl.h
> -- Looking for fcntl.h - found
> -- Looking for link.h
> -- Looking for link.h - not found
> -- Looking for malloc/malloc.h
> -- Looking for malloc/malloc.h - not found
> -- Looking for signal.h
> -- Looking for signal.h - found
> -- Looking for sys/ioctl.h
> -- Looking for sys/ioctl.h - not found
> -- Looking for sys/mman.h
> -- Looking for sys/mman.h - not found
> -- Looking for sys/param.h
> -- Looking for sys/param.h - found
> -- Looking for sys/resource.h
> -- Looking for sys/resource.h - not found
> -- Looking for sys/stat.h
> -- Looking for sys/stat.h - found
> -- Looking for sys/time.h
> -- Looking for sys/time.h - found
> -- Looking for sys/types.h
> -- Looking for sys/types.h - found
> -- Looking for sysexits.h
> -- Looking for sysexits.h - not found
> -- Looking for termios.h
> -- Looking for termios.h - not found
> -- Looking for unistd.h
> -- Looking for unistd.h - found
> -- Looking for valgrind/valgrind.h
> -- Looking for valgrind/valgrind.h - not found
> -- Looking for fenv.h
> -- Looking for fenv.h - found
> -- Looking for FE_ALL_EXCEPT
> -- Looking for FE_ALL_EXCEPT - found
> -- Looking for FE_INEXACT
> -- Looking for FE_INEXACT - found
> -- Performing Test HAVE_BUILTIN_THREAD_POINTER
> -- Performing Test HAVE_BUILTIN_THREAD_POINTER - Failed
> -- Looking for mach/mach.h
> -- Looking for mach/mach.h - not found
> -- Looking for CrashReporterClient.h
> -- Looking for CrashReporterClient.h - not found
> -- Looking for pfm_initialize in pfm
> -- Looking for pfm_initialize in pfm - not found
> -- Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
> -- Could NOT find LibXml2 (missing: LIBXML2_LIBRARY LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR)
> -- Looking for arc4random
> -- Looking for arc4random - not found
> -- Looking for backtrace
> -- Looking for backtrace - not found
> -- Could NOT find Backtrace (missing: Backtrace_LIBRARY Backtrace_INCLUDE_DIR)
> -- Performing Test C_SUPPORTS_WERROR_UNGUARDED_AVAILABILITY_NEW
> -- Performing Test C_SUPPORTS_WERROR_UNGUARDED_AVAILABILITY_NEW - Failed
> -- Looking for __register_frame
> -- Looking for __register_frame - not found
> -- Looking for __deregister_frame
> -- Looking for __deregister_frame - not found
> -- Looking for __unw_add_dynamic_fde
> -- Looking for __unw_add_dynamic_fde - not found
> -- Looking for _Unwind_Backtrace
> -- Looking for _Unwind_Backtrace - found
> -- Looking for getpagesize
> -- Looking for getpagesize - not found
> -- Looking for sysconf
> -- Looking for sysconf - not found
> -- Looking for getrusage
> -- Looking for getrusage - not found
> -- Looking for setrlimit
> -- Looking for setrlimit - not found
> -- Looking for isatty
> -- Looking for isatty - found
> -- Looking for futimens
> -- Looking for futimens - not found
> -- Looking for futimes
> -- Looking for futimes - not found
> -- Looking for sigaltstack
> -- Looking for sigaltstack - not found
> -- Looking for mallctl
> -- Looking for mallctl - not found
> -- Looking for mallinfo
> -- Looking for mallinfo - not found
> -- Looking for mallinfo2
> -- Looking for mallinfo2 - not found
> -- Looking for malloc_zone_statistics
> -- Looking for malloc_zone_statistics - not found
> -- Looking for getrlimit
> -- Looking for getrlimit - not found
> -- Looking for posix_spawn
> -- Looking for posix_spawn - not found
> -- Looking for pread
> -- Looking for pread - not found
> -- Looking for sbrk
> -- Looking for sbrk - not found
> -- Looking for strerror_r
> -- Looking for strerror_r - not found
> -- Looking for strerror_s
> -- Looking for strerror_s - found
> -- Looking for setenv
> -- Looking for setenv - not found
> -- Looking for _chsize_s
> -- Looking for _chsize_s - found
> -- Looking for _alloca
> -- Looking for _alloca - not found
> -- Looking for __alloca
> -- Looking for __alloca - found
> -- Looking for __chkstk
> -- Looking for __chkstk - not found
> -- Looking for __chkstk_ms
> -- Looking for __chkstk_ms - not found
> -- Looking for ___chkstk
> -- Looking for ___chkstk - found
> -- Looking for ___chkstk_ms
> -- Looking for ___chkstk_ms - found
> -- Looking for __ashldi3
> -- Looking for __ashldi3 - not found
> -- Looking for __ashrdi3
> -- Looking for __ashrdi3 - not found
> -- Looking for __divdi3
> -- Looking for __divdi3 - not found
> -- Looking for __fixdfdi
> -- Looking for __fixdfdi - not found
> -- Looking for __fixsfdi
> -- Looking for __fixsfdi - not found
> -- Looking for __floatdidf
> -- Looking for __floatdidf - not found
> -- Looking for __lshrdi3
> -- Looking for __lshrdi3 - not found
> -- Looking for __moddi3
> -- Looking for __moddi3 - not found
> -- Looking for __udivdi3
> -- Looking for __udivdi3 - not found
> -- Looking for __umoddi3
> -- Looking for __umoddi3 - not found
> -- Looking for __main
> -- Looking for __main - found
> -- Looking for __cmpdi2
> -- Looking for __cmpdi2 - not found
> -- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_MTIMESPEC_TV_NSEC
> -- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_MTIMESPEC_TV_NSEC - Failed
> -- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_MTIM_TV_NSEC
> -- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_MTIM_TV_NSEC - Failed
> -- Looking for __GLIBC__
> -- Looking for __GLIBC__ - not found
> -- Looking for proc_pid_rusage
> -- Looking for proc_pid_rusage - not found
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_ATOMICS_WITHOUT_LIB
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_ATOMICS_WITHOUT_LIB - Success
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_ATOMICS64_WITHOUT_LIB
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_ATOMICS64_WITHOUT_LIB - Success
> -- Performing Test LLVM_HAS_ATOMICS
> -- Performing Test LLVM_HAS_ATOMICS - Success
> -- LLVM host triple: x86_64-w64-windows-gnu
> -- Native target architecture is X86
> -- Threads enabled.
> -- Doxygen disabled.
> -- Ninja version: 1.11.1
> -- Could NOT find OCaml (missing: OCAMLFIND OCAML_VERSION OCAML_STDLIB_PATH)
> -- OCaml bindings disabled.
> -- Could NOT find Python module pygments
> -- Could NOT find Python module pygments.lexers.c_cpp
> -- Could NOT find Python module yaml
> -- LLVM default target triple: x86_64-w64-windows-gnu
> -- Performing Test C_SUPPORTS_CXX98_COMPAT_EXTRA_SEMI_FLAG
> -- Performing Test C_SUPPORTS_CXX98_COMPAT_EXTRA_SEMI_FLAG - Failed
> -- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_CXX98_COMPAT_EXTRA_SEMI_FLAG
> -- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_CXX98_COMPAT_EXTRA_SEMI_FLAG - Failed
> -- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_SUGGEST_OVERRIDE_FLAG
> -- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_SUGGEST_OVERRIDE_FLAG - Success
> -- Performing Test CXX_WSUGGEST_OVERRIDE_ALLOWS_ONLY_FINAL
> -- Performing Test CXX_WSUGGEST_OVERRIDE_ALLOWS_ONLY_FINAL - Success
> -- Performing Test C_WCOMMENT_ALLOWS_LINE_WRAP
> -- Performing Test C_WCOMMENT_ALLOWS_LINE_WRAP - Failed
> -- Performing Test C_SUPPORTS_CTAD_MAYBE_UNSPPORTED_FLAG
> -- Performing Test C_SUPPORTS_CTAD_MAYBE_UNSPPORTED_FLAG - Failed
> -- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_CTAD_MAYBE_UNSPPORTED_FLAG
> -- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_CTAD_MAYBE_UNSPPORTED_FLAG - Success
> -- Looking for os_signpost_interval_begin
> -- Looking for os_signpost_interval_begin - not found
> -- Performing Test HAS_WERROR_GLOBAL_CTORS
> -- Performing Test HAS_WERROR_GLOBAL_CTORS - Failed
> -- Looking for __x86_64__
> -- Looking for __x86_64__ - found
> -- Found Git: C:/DEVELOPMENT/Git/cmd/git.exe (found version "2.39.1.windows.1")
> -- LLVMHello ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
> -- Looking for logf128
> -- Looking for logf128 - not found
> -- Targeting AArch64
> -- Targeting AMDGPU
> -- Targeting ARM
> -- Targeting AVR
> -- Targeting BPF
> -- Targeting Hexagon
> -- Targeting Lanai
> -- Targeting LoongArch
> -- Targeting Mips
> -- Targeting MSP430
> -- Targeting NVPTX
> -- Targeting PowerPC
> -- Targeting RISCV
> -- Targeting Sparc
> -- Targeting SystemZ
> -- Targeting VE
> -- Targeting WebAssembly
> -- Targeting X86
> -- Targeting XCore
> -- BugpointPasses ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
> -- Google Benchmark version: v0.0.0, normalized to 0.0.0
> -- Looking for shm_open in rt
> -- Looking for shm_open in rt - not found
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_WALL
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_WALL - Success
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_WEXTRA
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_WEXTRA - Success
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_WSHADOW
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_WSHADOW - Success
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_WFLOAT_EQUAL
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_WFLOAT_EQUAL - Success
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_WOLD_STYLE_CAST
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_WOLD_STYLE_CAST - Success
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_WSUGGEST_OVERRIDE
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_WSUGGEST_OVERRIDE - Success
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_PEDANTIC
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_PEDANTIC - Success
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_PEDANTIC_ERRORS
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_PEDANTIC_ERRORS - Success
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_WSHORTEN_64_TO_32
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_WSHORTEN_64_TO_32 - Failed
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_FSTRICT_ALIASING
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_FSTRICT_ALIASING - Success
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS - Success
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_FNO_EXCEPTIONS
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_FNO_EXCEPTIONS - Success
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_WSTRICT_ALIASING
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_WSTRICT_ALIASING - Success
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_WD654
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_WD654 - Failed
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_WTHREAD_SAFETY
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_WTHREAD_SAFETY - Failed
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_COVERAGE
> -- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FLAG_COVERAGE - Success
> -- Compiling and running to test HAVE_GNU_POSIX_REGEX
> -- Performing Test HAVE_GNU_POSIX_REGEX -- failed to compile
> -- Compiling and running to test HAVE_POSIX_REGEX
> -- Performing Test HAVE_POSIX_REGEX -- failed to compile CMake Warning at
> D:/DEVELOPMENT/LLVM/llvm-project/third-party/benchmark/CMakeLists.txt:319
> (message):   Using std::regex with exceptions disabled is not fully
> supported
> 
> 
> -- Compiling and running to test HAVE_STEADY_CLOCK
> -- Performing Test HAVE_STEADY_CLOCK -- success
> -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
> -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
> -- Check if compiler accepts -pthread
> -- Check if compiler accepts -pthread - yes
> -- Found Threads: TRUE
> -- Compiling and running to test HAVE_PTHREAD_AFFINITY
> -- Performing Test HAVE_PTHREAD_AFFINITY -- failed to compile
> -- Configuring done (35.8s)
> -- Generating done (3.2s)
> -- Build files have been written to: D:/DEVELOPMENT/LLVM/llvm-project/build

I guess the problem may be related to os, because my os is windows, but the missing part mentioned in the logs are all based on linux.
I really have no idea what to do next does anybody know how to fix this? thanks a lot !

Nobody is going to click through those ten screenshots. Edit your question with a textual error message and the steps you took to configure LLVM and build it.

So, did you actually build LLVM? The CMake command you gave just sets up a build system. You still have to run cmake --build build --parallel to build LLVM. I would not be surprised if that actually generates the .inc files. EDIT: yes, it is generated as part of the build process. attributes.inc relevant definition

As you discovered, that Attributes.inc file (and others) are generated by the LLVM build system as part of the build process.
You need to actually build LLVM to get these files to appear:
cmake --build build --parallel

You may also want to cmake --install build LLVM to somewhere instead of keeping a full build tree lying around, but that is up to you.

Thank you so much!  Indeed I was not aware of the actual build process. Before the compiler course, I actually didn't use C++ at all. Seems I need to learn more fundamental knowledge about C++ tool chains.
